# Configure netbeans 8.0 gdb to work with gradle cpp plugin

Tags: c++, debugging, netbeans, gradle, gdb

Lately I've switched from Visual Studio in Windows 7 to Ubuntu with Netbeans 8.0 (C++). From that time I have big problem with debugging my application from NetBeans (gdb works perfectly fine). I have written hello world c++ with gradle to demonstrate my problem. I've spent a lot of time but without any significant progress.

### Gradle project

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

executables {
    helloWorld
}
binaries.all {
     cppCompiler.args "-g"
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 12;
    int c = a + b;
    puts("Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Then i build and run gdb**:

```
robert-Aspire-S3:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorld$ gradle helloWorldExecutable
robert-Aspire-S3:~/NetBeansProjects/helloWorld$ gdb ./build/binaries/helloWorldExecutable/helloWorld                     
....
Reading symbols from ./build/binaries/helloWorldExecutable/helloWorld...done.
(gdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1, main () at /home/robert/NetBeansProjects/helloWorld/src/helloWorld/cpp/main.cpp:5
5           int a = 10;
(gdb) n                                                                                                                         
6           int b = 12;
(gdb) print a
$1 = 10
(gdb) n
7           int c = a + b;
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hello World!!!
[Inferior 1 (process 3693) exited normally]
```

Next step was attaching to gdb process from Netbeans 8.0. I've also put breakpoint in NetBeans in the 5th line hoping I will get gdb output. 
[image: Attaching gdb]
[image: Breakpoint from NetBeans]

Sadly Netbeans is not hitting breakpoint in editor area and I don't know why. I have also opened **Debbuger Console** and I pasted [logs (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/bDjddBjs) for further informations.

**C++ Application**

When I created standard **C/C++ Application** from NetBeans wizard and try debug everything works well. 
[image: Cpp debugger]

For that session I've also [upload logs](http://pastebin.com/rstqL63h).

I have found one difference in logs:

- Gradle cpp: `10-file-symbol-file  "/usr/bin/gdb"`
- NetBeans cpp: `10-file-exec-and-symbols  "/home/robert/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cppapplication_1"`

So this is a problem with that one line with gradle ? 
If yes how I can fix it? 
Can anyone help me with attach NetBeans visual debugger to gradle cpp projects?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Which gradle cpp netbeans plugin are you using? The [official gradle netbeans plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support) seems to support only Java.

Comment: demosntsrated lines also are potential no-ops unless certain flags are given to GCC. unused local variable initialization

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in build.gradle so you must check the syntaxes used in gradle program. http://gradle.org/getting-started-native/ this site contain some examples. Read it fix your problem.